# nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR no such key

Tags: spring-boot

I am using this code to set value in redis(Java 8 + Spring Boot 2.1.12.RELEASE):

```
public List<App> getApps(App app) {
        String key = "app:list:" + app.getAppMark();
        String lockKey = "lock:" + key;
        List<App> apps = redisTemplate.opsForList().range(key, 0, -1);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(apps)) {
            return apps;
        }
        try {
            ELocker.lock(lockKey, BizGlobalConstant.DISTRIBUTE_LOCK_DEFAULT_EXPIRE_SECOND);
            apps = getDBApps(app);
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(apps)) {
                redisTemplate.opsForList().set(key, 0, apps);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            ELocker.unLock(lockKey);
        }
        return apps;
    }
```

when execute to `redisTemplate.opsForList().set` throw this error:

```
Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR no such key
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tweak code like this:

```
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    private ValueOperations<String, List<App>> listValueOperations;

    @PostConstruct
    public void before() {
        listValueOperations = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
    }

    @Override
    @UseSlave
    public List<App> getApps(App app) {
        String key = "app:list:" + app.getAppMark();
        String lockKey = "lock:" + key;
        List<App> apps = listValueOperations.get(key);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(apps)) {
            return apps;
        }
        try {
            ELocker.lock(lockKey, BizGlobalConstant.DISTRIBUTE_LOCK_DEFAULT_EXPIRE_SECOND);
            apps = getDBApps(app);
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(apps)) {
                listValueOperations.set(key, apps);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            ELocker.unLock(lockKey);
        }
        return apps;
    }
```